# Adverb or adjective in this case?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, word-order

I heard a native English speaker said:

> I am **severely** in need of it.

It sounds much better than

> I am **severe** in need of it.

to me.

But thinking more deeply, isn't *need* a noun here hence it should be an adjective *severe*? Like "I'm *good* in shape."

But using adverb still sound more natural to me in many cases(but not the *shape* case above), for example "They *inherently* in genes are cute."

So what should it use actually?

Comment: You have the preposition in the wrong place in the second sentence. It should read "*I am **in** severe need of it.*" Also, "They inherently in genes are cute" makes no sense... genes are the things your body is made of... as in DNA... Do you mean "jeans"? Even so, the sentence doesn't make sense. What are you trying to say?

Comment: @Catija I mean they are born cute.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind the usual position of adjectives and adverbs.

> I **am severely** in need of it.

is OK. *severely* (an adverb) modifies *am* (verb).
The second example needs to be:

> I am **in severe need** of it.

where *severe* (an adjective) modifies *need* (noun). A prepositional phrase in the predicate is appropriate since you can't have a direct object with *to be*.

The meanings are roughly the same, though the emphasis is a bit more on "I" in the first one, and on the "need" in the second one.